# Django models: how to handle conceptually similar ideas and somewhat repetitious elements

Tags: python, django, database

I am new to Django and databases.

Suppose I am trying to create a database filled with information about various nobility over time. So, there will be a number of different countries that might have a "monarch" position, held by various people, male and female, at different times. Several countries might call it King/Queen while perhaps just one will call it Tsar/Tsarina. But these are fixed.
My initial impression for modeling might be something like

```
class Person(models.Model):
    SEX_CHOICES = (
        'm': 'Male',
        'f': 'Female'
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    birthdate = models.DateField()
    sex = models.CharField(max_length = 2, choices = SEX_CHOICES)

    titles = models.ManyToManyField(Title, through='TitleOccupation')

class Country(models.Model):
    #...

class Title(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    #...


class TitleOccupation(models.Model):
    title = models.ForeignKey(Title)

    date_start = models.DateField()
    date_end = models.DateField(null = True, blank=True)
```

I'm trying to figure out how to incorporate the uniqueness of a country's title while recognizing that there are many similarities among them. A Title might represent the "monarch of England," and the monarch would be called a King if male or a Queen if female. There might be many other countries for which the monarch is called a King or Queen, but there are also unique titles representing the same idea for other countries as well.
I had thought of including some kind of extra model, like Position to represent monarchy, for example, and then somehow including choices for name prefixes (King, etc.) in there. But then it seems like I am generating more bulk.

```
class Position(model.Model):
    #...

    TITLES_MALE = (
        'King',
        'Tsar',
        'Emperor',
        ...
    )

    TITLES_FEMALE = (
        'Queen',
        'Tsarina',
        'Empress',
        ...
    )
```

At the same time, the less awkward option might be to include a male and female name prefix for each Title. But is this actually less awkward? Maybe this will result in a huge amount of wasted space and time when trying to, say, display a person's name.

```
p = Person.objects.get(name='???')
p.get_title(p.titles.filter(...))
```

where `get_title` would be some method in the Person model that looks for the Title's name prefix in either the male or female set depending on the Person's sex. This seems equally as awkward to me.

I have looked into some of Django's localization info for some insight, but I couldn't really extrapolated any of it to this sort of intra-language "localization."

Comment: Position w 3 fields.  Level (king, count, duke...) as a FK to say NobilityLevel. Sex, language/country.  PositionTitle is a lookup with title which stores tsarina for king,female,russian.  Also, titles would evolve in time too.